# ASP.NET code for file acceptance

Tags: android, .net

I have coded in android for sending a file using HTTP post. I am a newbie in .NET technologies, searching in the internet didn't be of any help,it would be of great help if any person provide me some link or code snippet or at least some hint on how to accept the file at the server side using ASP.NET.
The below is my android code :-

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;

String pathToOurFile = "/data/file_to_send.mp3";
String urlServer = "";
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs & Outputs
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

// Enable POST method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Exception handling
}
```

Comment: You are calling a PHP file, but ask for ASP.NET advice? What have you tried so far? What happens?

Comment: The thing is that I am newbie in .NET technologies, got the code snippet from
 http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

I need to code server side in ASP.NET, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please go back and indent your code like I hope you do in "real life".

Comment: Assuming your android code is working (I didn't test it), you will now set up an ASP.NET project, and in the Page you will be calling, you will investigate the Page.Request.Files collection. Good luck.

Comment: @Alexander. A code snippet would be of great help. Any link/ reference would do.

Comment: I'd rather you try yourself and understand what you are doing instead of forgeing pieces you collect together into something you won't be able to debug. Sorry if this is too blunt. Give it a go, and if you have problems, come back.

Comment: I get that,but I have got deadlines to meet, I understand your concern regarding the copy paste stuff, but you cant expect to do perfect work 'all' the time. :)